# Trying to modifiy back button for an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to modify the back button navigation for a specific activity but I'm having an error

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION CURRENT ACTIVITY : BookmarksActivity
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Bundle.unparcel()' on a null object reference
>           at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:250)
>           at android.content.Intent.putExtras(Intent.java:8597)
>           at usb.terminal.view.fragment.BookmarksFragment$2.onItemClick(BookmarksFragment.java:162)

I've tried two approach, I've modified the back button function in my ActionBarFragment. The problem with my second approach is that it goes to required activity as expected but it's keeps crashing with the error specified above when I'm clicking on an item in my list.

```
private void initListeners() {
    btnBackListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                Log.d("Back Button", "Back button pressed");

                int flag = BookmarksFragment.getFlag();
                Log.d("Flag Number", String.valueOf(flag));

                if (flag == 1){
                    BookmarksFragment class2 = new BookmarksFragment();
                    class2.fetchBookmarkCategories();
                }

                else {
                    if(getActivity()!=null) {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

and secondly instead of calling the function of the other class , I've tried to reload the activity using :

```
BookmarksFragment class2 = new BookmarksFragment();
                    class2.fetchBookmarkCategories();
```

This is my bookmark activity which I'm trying to get my desired function.

```
public class BookmarksActivity extends EmptyActivity {


    public BookmarksActivity() {
        super(new BookmarksFragment());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ((ActionBarFragment) actionBarFragment).updateTitle(R.string.bookmark_activity_title);
    }

}
```

This is my BookmarkFragment (only part of the code):

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.userId = PreferencesHelper.getPrefsUserId(ctx);
        categoriesListView = (NonScrollListView) view.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_categories_list);
        recipesListView = (NonScrollListView) view.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_recipes_list);
        noResultLayout = (LinearLayout)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.bookmark_recipes_empty_panel);

        scrollButton = (CardView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.load_more_button);
        scrollAction = (LinearLayout) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.load_more_action_layout);
        scrollLoading = (LinearLayout) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.load_more_loading_layout);
        scrollLoadingImage = (ImageView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.load_more_loading_icon);

        recipesAdapter = new RecipesAdapter(ctx, recipesLinkedList);

        categoriesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Category category = categoriesLinkedList.get(position);
                fetchBookmarksFromCategory(category.getId());
            }
        });

        recipesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, RecipePagerActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = activity.getIntent().getExtras();
                intent.putExtra("Check_Status", 1);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                int recipeId = recipesLinkedList.get(position).getId();
                int recipeCount = recipesLinkedList.get(position).getNbFavorite();
                boolean recipeStatus = recipesLinkedList.get(position).isFavorite();
                intent.putExtra("Recipe Status", recipeStatus);
                intent.putExtra("Recipe_Count", recipeCount);
                intent.putExtra(RecipesManager.KEY_ID_RECIPE, recipeId);

            }
        });

        setSpinner(view);

        fetchBookmarkLists();
    }
```

Both approaches are giving me the same errors. Can someone help with a solution here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `activity.getIntent().getExtras()` is returning null value.

Please try to null check before using `extras` and assign `new Bundle()` if needed, something like...

```
                int recipeId = recipesLinkedList.get(position).getId();
                int recipeCount = recipesLinkedList.get(position).getNbFavorite();
                boolean recipeStatus = recipesLinkedList.get(position).isFavorite();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, RecipePagerActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = activity.getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras == null) extras = new Bundle();  //solution

                extras.putInt("Check_Status", 1);
                extras.putInt(RecipesManager.KEY_ID_RECIPE, recipeId);
                extras.putInt("Recipe_Count", recipeCount);
                extras.putBoolean("Recipe Status", recipeStatus);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
```